# Asp .net MVC 5 Route Attribute with id between route

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I´m trying to set up a route in MVC so that when POSTing to the following url

```
/organizations/55/repositories
```

I get all the repositories for organization 55
I've tried using the following route but to no avail, it never reaches the controller action method

```
[Route("/organizations/{id}/repositories")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Repositories(long id, OrganizationSearchParametersDTO parameters)
```

However if I do it in the RegisterRoutes method, it works:

```
routes.MapRoute("OrganizationControllerRoute", "organizations/{id}/repositories", new {controller = "Organizations", action = "Repositories"});
```

But I'd prefer to have it running using attributes because it's our way to work
What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: You do not need the leading `/`

Comment: just tried it, still doesn't work :(

Comment: You have the method marked as a POST - you cannot navigate to a POST method

Comment: i'm doing a POST with data, i'll edit the question to make it less confusing sorry
also i've tried something else ,adding the route in the RegisteRoutes method and that works, so it must be something wrong with the attribute definition. will also update the question with that

Comment: Have you added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to the `RegisterRoutes()` method (before any route definitions)?

Comment: that did it! thanks a lot mate
you can add that comment as a response and i'll accept it as valid
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `routes.MapRoute(..)` definition works, but not the `[Route(...)]` attribute, it means that you have not enabled attribute routing in the `RouteConfig.cs` file

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Add the following line before any route definitions
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        ... // add routes.MapRoute(...) definitions as required
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside to this, It is useful to know that If you ever use APIControllers they use exactly the same attribute decorations but also need hooking up with a completely different Map method (MapHttpAttributeRoutes) in your WebApiConfig. Not important for the answer to this question but hopefully is useful to someone who finds this question when looking for Routes not working.

Comment: i´ve used both in the past, but I guess that usually when creating a new project it adds the method call for you. somebody must have deleted it in this project and therefore it wasn´t there. but now i know about it for the future!